# Get the current Data Item (row) on DataBinding an Ext.NET GridPanel

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, extjs, ext.net

I need to setup each row in an ext.NET GridPanel in the `OnDataBinding` event. How can I get the current data item at **server side**?

```
<uc:GridPanel ID="egrBills" runat="server" Border="false" Layout="Fit">
 <Store>
  <ext:Store runat="server" OnDataBinding="OnDataBinding_EventHandler" ID="MainStore">
   <!-- ............ -->
```

```
protected void OnDataBinding_EventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //How do I get current data item?           
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Ext.NET, there is no server-side row databinding event. The client-side `<Renderer>` functionality may be an option.

Answer (score 1):

```
DataRowView dr = (DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem;
string CollegeName= Convert.ToString(dr["CollegeName"]);
```

Here the CollegeName is the name of the column it will give the value at per row on the OnDataBinding event

Comment: Cannot convert type 'System.EventArgs' to 'System.Data.DataRowView'